# What are reasonable expectations for flow times? My IT department is raising alarms based on a worst-case scenario

Tags: power-automate, performance

I'm dealing with a philosophical conflict and need a technical way to validate my solution: I want to use Power Automate to leverage primarily SharePoint and Forms to do what I used to do with SharePoint designer. My IT department isn't resourced to be responsive to some of the needs that can be met this way, but they also don't want anyone else stepping in to solve those problems, either, so they're intent on proving that Power Platform shouldn't be used.

For example, we have a user requirement to have members drop a file in a library and then have the permissions adjusted so that only site owners and the contributing user can see or edit it (so it's invisible to other members). We've built this flow that accomplishes that and is working as expected:

[image: Flow overview]

Reports show that the flow takes 2 seconds to run, but in my testing we've had other members sitting on the library page and refreshing to try to see a file that's not theirs as soon as it was dropped in and they haven't been able to even catch a glimpse of it, possibly because other users' access will disappear as soon as the http request to delete all permissions has run, midway through the flow.

My IT department, though, is pushing back and saying that it's not a suitable solution because flows (in general) may take 1-5 minutes to run, so those files would be exposed to other users for longer than they should be.

I can understand that if adoption increases (of this flow or the platform as a whole) then my current <2 second execution time may increase. It seems like it would require a lot, though, to go from 2 seconds to five minutes.

Are there technical tools or steps I can take to predict expected execution time as load increases, given the low complexity of this flow, or am I stuck with no way to address concerns about Microsoft's  general "may take up to five minutes" blanket disclaimer?

Comment: also, Flows might outright fail sometimes.

Comment: Agreed - assuming the flow has been tested and isn't failing due to errors in how it was created, do you know if there are any statistics on how many/how often failure happens at the platform level?